# Multiple Foreign key SqlAlchemy join error in flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes. An institution can have multiple students. Hence, I have two classes as given below:

```
class University(db.Model):
    country = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    students = db.relationship('Student', backref='phd_granting_university', lazy='dynamic')

class Student(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    phd_graduation_year = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phd_granting_university_name = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('university.name'), primary_key=True)
    phd_granting_university_country = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('university.country'), primary_key=True)
```

I get the following error:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on
> relationship University.students - there are multiple foreign key
> paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument,
> providing a list of those columns which should be counted as
> containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite foreign key must be [declared at the table level](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html?highlight=check%20constraint#defining-foreign-keys).  To do this in SQLAlchemy's ORM, the constraint is declared in the `__table_args__` attribute:

```py
class Student(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    phd_graduation_year = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phd_granting_university_name = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    phd_granting_university_country = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [phd_granting_university_name, phd_granting_university_country],
            ['university.name', 'university.country'],
        ),
    )
```

This will generate this DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
        name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        phd_graduation_year INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        phd_granting_university_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        phd_granting_university_country VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (name, phd_graduation_year, phd_granting_university_name, phd_granting_university_country), 
        FOREIGN KEY(phd_granting_university_name, phd_granting_university_country) REFERENCES university (name, country)
)
```